# How To Create Two Targets But Only One Application Bundle?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am using Xcode 4 and have created my two targets in my one project.  One is the main application with a GUI (I will call it main) and the second is a GUI less helper application (I will call it helper).  I have added a Copy Files in my Build Phase which copies the helper app into the Resources folder of the main app.  All of that is working great.

When I Archive my project it only gives me the option to Build Products, and then it creates two separate bundles, one called main and one called helper (main also has helper in it).

How can I make the helper app only get built in main?

Thanks.